# Looking to hide indicator on all timeframes other than the 5 minute

Tags: pine-script, trading, forex

Ive got a code to show engulfing candles and i just want it to show on the 5 minute timeframe and be hidden on everything else. Is there a way todo this?

This is the code:

```
//@version=4
study("AW Enties Current", overlay=true)


// Get bearish engulfing
bearishEC = close < open[1] and close[1] > open[1]
bullishEC = close > open[1] and close[1] < open[1]

// Plot EC to chart
plotshape(bearishEC, title="Short", location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, transp=0, 
style=shape.triangledown)
plotshape(bullishEC, title="Long", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, transp=0, 
style=shape.triangleup)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
study("AW Enties Current", overlay=true)

// Get bearish engulfing
bearishEC = close < open[1] and close[1] > open[1]
bullishEC = close > open[1] and close[1] < open[1]

show = timeframe.period == "5"

// Plot EC to chart
plotshape(show and bearishEC, title="Short", location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, transp=0, style=shape.triangledown)
plotshape(show and bullishEC, title="Long", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, transp=0, style=shape.triangleup)
```